# Relation on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $R$ be a complete ordered relation on $A$. For any plane $P_{XY}$ parallel to $XY$ plane $R|_{{{{(P_{XY}}\cap A)}\times} {(P_{XY}\cap A)}}$ is anti symmetric and transitive. This is also true for the planes which are parallel to $YZ$ and $XZ$ planes. Now is it possible to proof that the relation $R$ will also be anti symmetric and transitive on $A$? If not please provide an example.

Comment: Here I ment that the relation restricted on the planes intersection with the set $A$ is as anti symmetric and transitive.

Comment: By a "complete ordered relation", do you just mean a relation where for all $a,b$, you have $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$?

Comment: complete ordered  relation means $\forall a,b \in A$ either $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$ or both will be in the relation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you define $aRb$ as:

$$aRb: \begin{cases}
 a\preceq b & \text{ if } \exists j(a_j\ne b_j) \\
 \sin \sum \pi {a_j\pi\over6} - \sin\sum {b_j\pi\over6} \le 1/2 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

where $\preceq$ is the lexicographic order. It's obvious that this is an complete relation.

If you consider the restriction of this to one of the mentioned plane that means that one of the components will be constant and hence coincide, so the restriction of the relation becomes lexical ordering. So it's then anti symmetric and transitive.

However if we set $a=(3,3,3)$, $b=(2,2,2)$ and $c=(0,0,0)$ (meaning $\sin\sum a_j = 1$, $\sin\sum b_j=1/2$ and $\sin\sum c_j=0$) we see that $aRb$, $bRa$, $bRc$ and $cRb$, but $a\not Rc$. So $R$ is neither anti symmetric nor transitive.

Comment: Well if we add another condition in the question such as : let $a,b,c$ are 3 points of $A$ and there is a plane $P_{XY}$ contains $a,b$  and also there is a plane $P_{YZ}$ contains $b,c$ and $aRb$, $bRc$ holds then also $aRc$ holds. And it’s also true for all other planes as mentioned. Then can we disproof or prove that the relation is as asked above?